# Как правильно запросить метод из Update по таймеру?

Tags: javascript, unity3d

Есть скрипт, ведущий обратный отсчет, в update. Каждые 30 мне секунд необходимо выводить метод TimerStatus. Но у меня метод выводится несколько раз, пока время по таймеру равно 30. Помогите это победить!

```
function Update()
{
  if (!isTimerEnd) {
    timer -= Time.deltaTime; 
  } 

  if (timer > 0) {
    var mDisplay : String = parseInt( timer / 60 ).ToString();

    var sDisplay : String = parseInt( timer ).ToString();

    if ( (timer - ( parseInt(mDisplay) * 60)) > 10 ) {
         sDisplay = parseInt( timer - ( parseInt(hDisplay) * 60) ).ToString();
    } 
    else {
      mDisplay = "0" + parseInt( timer - 
                          ( parseInt(hDisplay) * 60) ).ToString(); 
    }

    if (sDisplay == "30" && !calledTimerStatus ) {
       calledTimerStatus = true;
       TimerStatus();
    } else calledTimerStatus = false;

    displayText.text = sDisplay + mDisplay;

  }
}
function TimerStatus() {
  Debug.Log("30 sec stat");
}
```

Результат на 30 секунде:

[image: Результат работы скрипта]

Answer (score 1):

В вашей ситуации легче было бы сделать нужный вам метод сопрограммой (coroutine), тогда вам бы не пришлось реализовывать собственный таймер для этих целей и код получился бы более компактным и простым. Посмотрите [пример](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) в официальной документации.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду вместо вызова метода TimerStatus использовать корутину? Или полностью заменить метод Update на корутины?

Comment: если смотреть только на приведенный пример кода, то в нем можно полностью заменить весь Update на 1 вызов коротины TimeStatus с интервалом в 30 секунд

Comment: а как же тогда вывод displayText.text

Comment: можно и корутину запустить с интервалом в 1 секунду, для обновления текста, и проверку на 30 секунд. По факту будет даже точнее потому что deltaTime величина не фиксированная, а вычисляемая

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам подойдет метод [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)
Он периодически вызывает указанную функцию.
В вашем случае примерно такой код:

```
function Start() {
  InvokeRepeating("TimerStatus", 30.0f, 30.0f);
}
```

Можно и ваш код исправить. Дело в том, что после выставления calledTimerStatus 
 в true, на сл кадр тридцатой секунды срабатывает блок else, и выставляет его обратно в false. Попробуйте так:

```
if (sDisplay == "30" && !calledTimerStatus ) {
   calledTimerStatus = true;
   TimerStatus();
} 
if (sDisplay != "30") calledTimerStatus = false; // флаг уберется только на сл. секунду
```